# Bind Variables in Teradata

Tags: sql, binding, teradata

I have been told that binding variables to a query in Teradata could improve its performances because the query would be always the same, so Teradata would not re-prepare nor re-parse the SQL statement and would rather reuse the execution plan stored in memory of the session.

Example, I have the following macro:

```
REPLACE MACRO DB.MACRO(USER_ACCOUNT_ID# VARCHAR(100))
AS (
    SELECT USER_ACCOUNT_ID
    ,USER_ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
    ,CAST(TD_DATE_KEY_TO_DATE(DATE_KEY) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS "DATE"
    ,CLUSTER_DESC AS CLUSTER_DESCRIPTION
    FROM DB.VIEW
    WHERE USER_ACCOUNT_ID = :USER_ACCOUNT_ID#;
);
```

Which I execute like this: `EXECUTE DB.MACRO('123');`

With query binding, the statement would like this `EXECUTE DB.MACRO(?);` 
with the actual value of the `USER_ACCOUNT_ID` supplied in some way.

How can I do query binding on such a statement in order to avoid both query prepartion and parsing time?

Comment: This sounds like query parameters.  The way to do it depends on your application.  .net has one way, php another, coldfusion another, etc.

Comment: Where are you executing this sql statement? Is it in a sql client? If so you could probably get away with `Execute DB.Macro(?paramname);` and it may prompt you for a value. That being said, if it is in a sql client, then I can't imagine you getting any performance gain which makes your question not make sense.

Comment: I'm passing the EXECUTE statement from a Python Flask application to Teradata REST API. Teradata API provides a parameter which I can use to pass the `USER_ACCOUNT_ID` and I noticed the query was properly binded when used it, but there was still some query preparation time which I am trying to get rid off (if possible?).

Comment: How much time is your parsing (prepare) costing your transaction and is it impacting your SLA? The complexity of the view being accessed is going to drive this. You may be able to improve performance of the parsing if join elimination can be accomplished. This may require physical implementation changes at the database level to address soft-ri or unique secondary indexes.